# How can I use the hide/show toggle when clicking on text?

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to click on the first line of text, which will then expand the rest of the paragraph. But I also want to be able to close the text by clicking on that same first line again. I have written some code for it, but I am very elementary in JS. I would appreciate getting help on this. Thank you.

Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JUtcX/868/

```js
$('.expand').each(function() {
  var reducedHeight = $(this).height();
  $(this).css('height', 'auto');
  var fullHeight = $(this).height();
  $(this).height(reducedHeight);

  $(this).data('reducedHeight', reducedHeight);
  $(this).data('fullHeight', fullHeight);
}).click(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    height: $(this).height() ==
      $(this).data('reducedHeight') ? $(this).data('fullHeight') : $(this).data('reducedHeight')
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.expand {
  height: 14pt;
  padding: 2px;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" class="expand">
  The day after his forty-eighth birthday was the same day Theo Bitner’s seventy-five-year-old mother Friended him on Facebook. It was also the same day his wife told him he needed to see a doctor. Or a therapist. “It’s your mood,” she said. “It sucks.”
</div>
```

Comment: So what's not working? Your fiddle seems fine.

Comment: For some reason, it's not working on WordPress. So I was wondering if there is a more cleaner way to write it.

Comment: He just wants to be able to click the first line to toggle it back down when expanded.

Comment: I am not sure why it's not working on WordPress, or if WP is blocking something So I don't if there is an easier/cleaner way to write this.

Comment: where did you put the JS in Wordpress?

Comment: in shortcode part of WP

Answer (score 0):

check this way:

```
$('.expand').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass( "open" )){
    $(this).removeClass("open");
  }else{
    $(this).addClass("open");
  }
});
```

I just checked if the paragraph were open, and after that I add or remove the class `.open` to the content.

the css:

```
.expand {
    max-height: 14pt;
    padding: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;  
    transition: max-height 0.5s;
}

.expand.open{
   max-height: 15em;
}
```

[here the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JUtcX/869/)

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **toggle()**
http://jsfiddle.net/JUtcX/870/

jQuery

```
$('.firstLine').click(function (){
$('.secondLine').toggle();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="firstLine">
The day after his forty-eighth birthday was the same day Theo Bitner’s 
seventy-five-year-old mother Friended him on Facebook.

<div class="secondLine">
It was also the same day his wife told him he needed to see a doctor. Or a 
therapist. “It’s your mood,” she said. “It sucks.” </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.secondLine {display: none;}
```